# Check if Radio Button is Checked and if Value Matches

Tags: jquery

Wracking my brain trying to figure this out. I'm not the greatest with Jquery but know enough to kinda get by. Right now I am trying to develop something that will check if a radio button in a group is checked and then to see if its value matches so it can then show the correct corresponding section. I have a crude JSFiddle made that is close to my staging site's set up.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Oak</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Oak_0' checked="checked">

    <label>Brown Maple</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Brown Maple_1'>

    <label>Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Cherry_2'>

    <label>Quartersawn White Oak</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Quartersawn White Oak_3'>

    <label>Hard Maple</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Hard Maple_4'>

    <label>Hickory</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='Hickory_5'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
</div>
<div class="stains-container">
  <div class="oak-stains-div">
    <h4>Oak</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="b-maple-stains-div">
    <h4>Brown Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="cherry-stains-div">
    <h4>Cherry</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="qswo-stains-div">
    <h4>Quartersawn White Oak</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="h-maple-stains-div">
    <h4>Hard Maple</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
  <div class="hickory-stains-div">
    <h4>Hickory</h4>
    <label>Michael's Cherry</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Rich Tobacco</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <label>Dark Knight</label>
    <input type='radio' name="tmcp_radio_0" class='some-class-of-radiogroup' value='value'>

    <!-- Many Others... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// Create Variables
    var stains = $(".stains-container");
    // Check if Oak is checked
    var $oakchecked = $("input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $oakactive = $(".b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if B. Maple is checked
    var $bmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $bmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Cherry is checked
    var $cherrychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $cherryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if QSWO is checked
    var $qswochecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.h-maple-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $qswoactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if H. Maple is checked
    var $hmaplechecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.hickory-stains");
    var $hmapleactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .hickory-stains-div li");
    // Check if Hickory is checked
    var $hickorychecked = $("input.oak-stains, input.b-maple-stains, input.cherry-stains, input.qswo-stains, input.h-maple-stains");
    var $hickoryactive = $(".oak-stains-div li, .b-maple-stains-div li, .cherry-stains-div li, .qswo-stains-div li, .h-maple-stains-div li");


// Check if a button is pre-selected and if its value matches
var radio_buttons = $("input[name='tmcp_radio_0']");
    if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("OAK is selected");
        $(".oak-stains-div").show();
        $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
        $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Brown Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("B MAPLE is selected");
        $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
        $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Cherry_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("CHERRY is selected");
        $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
        $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("QSWO is selected");
        $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
        $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
        $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Hard Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("H MAPLE is selected");
        $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
        $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":checked") && /^Hickory_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("HICKORY is selected");
        $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
        $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
        $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
    } else if( radio_buttons.is(":not(:checked)")) {
        alert("NOTHING is selected");
        $(".stains-container").hide();
    } 
    // Check if Oak is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".oak-stains-div").show();
            $oakchecked.prop('checked', false);
            $oakactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        }  else {
            $(".oak-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if B. Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Brown Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").show();
            $bmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $bmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".b-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Cherry is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Cherry_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".cherry-stains-div").show();
            $cherrychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $cherryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".cherry-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if QSWO is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Quartersawn White Oak_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".qswo-stains-div").show();
            $qswochecked.prop('checked', false);
            $qswoactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".qswo-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hard Maple is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hard Maple_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").show();
            $hmaplechecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hmapleactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".h-maple-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });

    // Check if Hickory is selected or pre-selected
    radio_buttons.on('change',function(){
        if ( /^Hickory_\d$/.test($(this).val())) {
            stains.show();
            $(".hickory-stains-div").show();
            $hickorychecked.prop('checked', false);
            $hickoryactive.removeClass( "tc-active" );
        } else {
            $(".hickory-stains-div").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amishdirect/h2acf6n3/4/

The current issue is even though I have an input with 'checked="checked"' I can not have it recognize that option is checked. I've tried "prop", "is", and "attr" but none pick up the option is checked. This is even just seeing it would see if it was or wasn't. Right now I am stuck because of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I will also say the JS is crude and most likely can be improved and condensed. This is just what I have so I am thankful for any suggestions to improving it as well!

Comment: Bumping for exile.

Comment: We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Ah sorry. The code works except for the portion I was asking on. I'll start a question over at Stackoverflow then. Thanks!